# Go file server from hidden directory

Tags: go

I was setting up a file server handler for certbot using `net/http`'s `FileServer` handler and ran into some odd behavior setting the file server's root directory to a hidden directory.

I have a directory structure as follows:

```
certbot/
 |- .well-known/
 |    |- test.txt
 |- well-known/
      |- test.txt
```

All with the same user/group/permissions.

The following handler fails to serve test.txt (returns a 404 for GET /.well-known/test.txt):

```
http.Handle("/.well-known/", http.StripPrefix("/.well-known/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./certbot/.well-known"))))
```

However, these both work:

```
http.Handle("/.well-known/", http.StripPrefix("/.well-known/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./certbot/well-known"))))
http.Handle("/.well-known/", http.StripPrefix("/.well-known/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./certbot/.well-known/"))))
```

I'm wondering why I have to add the trailing slash when serving from `./certbot/.well-known` but not from `./certbot/well-known`.  I don't see anything in the [net/http source code](https://github.com/golang/go/tree/master/src/net/http) that would cause this.  The [http.Dir documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Dir) states that it will allow access to directories that begin with a period.  Why is the trailing slash needed in the one handler but not the other?

I'm using go v1.9.2 on a CentOS 7 Digital Ocean droplet.

Comment: unable to reproduce, your first line without `/` works. (with go 1.9.2 on CentOS 7 on digiocean droplet)